# How to query (Sale or Discount) and at least two fruits

Tags: solr

example query:

```
(Sale OR Discount) AND (Apple OR Banana OR Raspberry)
```

now I would like to have (Sale or Discount) and at least two fruits.

At the moment I am using the edismax parser which has the mm (minimum should match) parameter. But how would mm apply to the query above? Would mm=2 require two terms on both sides of AND?

Update: MatsLindh already pointed out the use of filter queries which is a good solution in gerneal. In my use case I hope to find any solution **keeping it all in the main query**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `Sale OR Discount` clause to a `fq` - the filter query will be used to further filter the result set returned from the first set of terms. You can then use `mm=2` to match two fruits as your main query.

```
q=Apple Banana Raspberry&mm=2&fq=field:(Sale OR Discount)
```

Comment: +1 this seems indeed like a good solution in general. Can you think of any solution keeping it a single query?

Comment: The `mm` parameter should only affect optional clauses, so `+(Sale OR Discount) Apple Banana Raspberry` with `mm=2` might work. Check the output from `debugQuery=true` to see how the query is expanded.